# Exception in asynchronous call messes up execution

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I am making two `httpClient.GetAsync()` calls.

According to the requirement, one of two calls will always throw a **"No host known"** exception and one will return a proper `HttpResponseMessage` object.

My problem is determining the bool value **only** after both async `httpClient` calls finish.

```
public async Task<bool> BothHttpCallsTask(string hostName)
{
    bool response1 = false;
    bool response2 = false;
    try
    {
        //httpClient and the GetAsync() are inside this method
        response1 = await CheckRedirectionBool(url1); 
        response2 = await CheckRedirectionBool(url2);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //when exception is caught here, the method evaluates as false
        //as response2  is still not executed
    }
    return response1 || response2 ;
}
```

How do I make the execution only evaluate when both async calls complete successfully (keeping in mind the mandatory exception makes the return statement evaluate before response 2 can get a value from its execution)
I need to return true if even one of the two http calls are successful.

Comment: Could you simply wrap each in its own exception handler?  This way you know which one past etc.

Comment: I agree with @JonH

Comment: wow that was it. Thank you for this comment, I'll add it as an answer

Comment: I do have exceptionhanding in CheckRedirectionBool, but the exception does not get caught there, only in ```BothHttpCallsTask```

Comment: What is the best practice to place try catch blocks for async http calls? if you have any resources i'll appreciate being redirected there

Comment: *"I need to return true if even one of the two http calls are successful."* <== This requirement implies that a successful first call makes the second call redundant, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is determining the bool value only after both async httpClient calls finish.

If you want to treat an exception the same as returning `false`, then I recommend writing a little helper method:

```
async Task<bool> TreatExceptionsAsFalse(Func<Task<bool>> action)
{
  try { return await action(); }
  catch { return false; }
}
```

Then it becomes easier to use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public async Task<bool> BothHttpCallsTask(string hostName)
{
  var results = await Task.WhenAll(
      TreatExceptionsAsFalse(() => CheckRedirectionBool(url1)),
      TreatExceptionsAsFalse(() => CheckRedirectionBool(url2))
  );
  return results[0] || results[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually used the two try catch blocks but it seemed really regressive. I checked this question on a whim today to see if it had updates and this approach worked beautifully. It really outlines my lack of understanding of the asynchronous world.

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply wrap each in its own exception handler?
For instance:

```
try{
 response1 = ...
}
catch(Exception e){
 //set some flag here
}

try{
 response2 = ...
}
catch(Exception e){
 //set some flag here
}
```

This way you know which one past vs which one didn't and set some flags based on that condition, etc.